# Why signal handler goes to infinite loop? - SIGSEGV

Tags: c, linux

Any idea why the signal handler goes to infinite loop?

Here is the code.
Please help me.

```
enter code here
 9 void SIGSEGV_handler(int signal)
10 {
11  printf("Segmentation fault caught....\n");
12  printf("Value of instance variable: i = %d\n\n", i);
13 } 
16 
17 int main()
18 {
19  char *mallocPtr, *callocPtr, *reallocPtr, *memalignPtr, *vallocPtr;
20  struct sigaction sa;
21 
22  sa.sa_handler=SIGSEGV_handler;
23  sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);
24 
37 
38  printf("The segmentation fault handler will be entered for i = 3, 4, 5 and 6\n");
39 
40 
41  for(i=0; i<7; i++)
42   {
43    printf("i = %d\n",i);
44 
45    mallocPtr=(char*)malloc(3);
46    printf("Malloc address : %x\n",mallocPtr);
47    strcpy(mallocPtr, "Hhvhgvghsvxhvshxv");
48    puts(mallocPtr);
```

Comment: Is it just me, or you haven't posted the whole `for` loop ? Maybe further down the line you are doing something to `i` and I do believe that you declared it globally and that alone is a bad thing to do

Comment: You cannot reliably invoke printf in a signal handler.  You cannot reliably return from a handler for SIGSEGV (you should exit instead).

Comment: No, i cannot exit..because in my case i need to catch the intervals it is going to handler (may be 3 to 6 secs).

Comment: @SS 'Kain': The other part of code are not relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The default action for `SIGSEGV` is to terminate your process. But you install a handler and override this:

```
/* Does nothing to "fix" what was wrong with the faulting
 * instruction.
 */
void SIGSEGV_handler(int signal)
{
    printf("Segmentation fault caught....\n");
    printf("Value of instance variable: i = %d\n\n", i);
}
```

So for every instruction that triggers a sigsegv, this handler is called **and the instruction is restarted**. But your handler did nothing to fix what was wrong in the first place with the faulting instruction.

In conclusion, when the instruction is restarted, it will fault again. And again, and again and... you get the idea.

Comment: But i expect: At the faulting instruction, the handler will be called, and on return it should go to the next line of code, right? (next line i mean, the line after the faulting instruction)

Comment: @kingsmasher1 No. It doesn't go to the next line. It attempts to execute the current instruction again.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: in object code, there's no notion of a "next line". It's just processor instructions.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 By the way, you do realize calling `printf` from a signal handler is unsafe, right ?

Comment: If it went to the next line instead of restarting the interrupted instruction (which has not completed due to the exception), consider how normal signal handling would work: a signal would be received, causing the current instruction to not only be interrupted but to also be missed... imagine trying to debug that! SIGSEGV handlers are just signal handlers to handle a signal sent by the system.

Comment: @cnicutar: Yes it is unsafe, and i need to remove it.

Comment: @cnicutar: Is there any way to correct it so that the handler works? Something using sigsetjmp longjmp?

Comment: @kingsmasher1 `siglongjmp` might work but personally I would to to great lengths to avoid using it.

Comment: @cnicutar: Can you kindly help me with a code snippet with that..it would be of huge help.

Answer (score 7):

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html#tag_02_04

> The behavior of a process is undefined after it returns normally from a signal-catching function for a SIGBUS,  SIGFPE, SIGILL, or SIGSEGV signal that was not generated by kill(),  sigqueue(),  or raise().