# How to write a segmentation fault handler, so that the faulty instruction is not restarted? (C and Linux)

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

I wrote a segmentation fault handler but the problem is, the instruction at which the fault is happening is restarted after going to the handler, and this causes the handler to go to infinite loop.

I want the handler to work such that after reaching the handler, the instruction following the faulty instruction should be executed such that it does not go to infinite loop. Can anyone please help me with some code snippet?

I am using C and Linux.

Comment: you should terminate after sigsegv (unless you're playing with mmap and want sigsegv to happen)

Comment: I don't wish to terminate, because i want to check the instances (time) at which the program enters the handler. I have written a tool for memory overwrite detect (similar to efence) at which the overwrites are detected in intervals (3 to 6 secs as an example), so i want to check that at 3secs, 4secs, 5secs and 6secs it enters the nadler. But for 7th second it should not call the handler.

Comment: Yeah, calling a handler for SIGSEGV allows you maybe to clean up or save some stuff, but you cannot evade termination and somehow "fix" the error, because the invalid access has already happened; or at least there's no meaningful state for the program to be in.

Comment: How is this question any different from the pretty much [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6981325/572743) asked 20 mins earlier?

Comment: I think you have some difficulty in getting the proper english, first was related to `why it goes to infite loop`, and second is `how to write a handler.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out an alternate and perhaps easier way to write a segmentation fault handler. Although user78863 answer and effort is praiseworthy, but seeing the complexity of code and difficult in porting, i think my solution is better. So i will accept my answer.

Here is the link to the code: [Can we reset sigsetjmp to return "0" again (Reset sigsetjmp)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985463/can-we-reset-sigsetjmp-to-return-0-again-reset-sigsetjmp/6985530#6985530)

Answer (score 6):

#### Warning: I do not recommend doing this. Listen to the comments telling you to find some other way to solve you problem

I'd also like to re-iterate Henning Makholms warning that it will be extremely architecture-specific and nonportable. It will be maintenance hell and you will have to manually handle lots of different instructions unless it is one specific instruction sequence you're looking for (as in the below example).

With that said if you *still* want to do it, it can be done in the following manner:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

#define __USE_GNU
#include <signal.h>

void action(int sig, siginfo_t* siginfo, void* context)
{
    sig=sig; siginfo=siginfo;// ignore warning

    // get execution context
    mcontext_t* mcontext = &((ucontext_t*)context)->uc_mcontext;

    // find out what instruction faulted
#if defined(__x86_64)
    uint8_t* code = (uint8_t*)mcontext->gregs[REG_RIP];
    if (code[0] == 0x88 && code[1] == 0x10) { // mov %dl,(%rax)
        mcontext->gregs[REG_RIP] += 2; // skip it!
        return;
    }
#elif defined(__i386)
    uint8_t* code = (uint8_t*)mcontext->gregs[REG_EIP];
    if (code[0] == 0x88 && code[1] == 0x10) { // mov %dl,(%eax)
        mcontext->gregs[REG_EIP] += 2; // skip it!
        return;
    }
#else
#error "Unsupported system"
#endif
    // unknown/unhandled instruction failed...

    // only for debugging, shouldn't print stuff in a signal handler
    int i = 0; 
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%2.2X ", code[i]);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    exit(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    // install SIGSEGV handler
    struct sigaction act;
    memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));
    act.sa_sigaction = action;
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    if (sigaction(SIGSEGV, &act, NULL) < 0) {
        perror("sigaction");
        return 1;
    }

    // cause fault
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ((unsigned char*)0)[i] = i;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here I have only handled one specific instruction sequence for x86 32- and 64-bit, though it should be trivial (if tedious) to support more architectures and instructions.

Update: You (now) mention that you are on an ARM machine. That should actually make it easier as the instructions are always 32-bit (except in thumb mode) if I'm not mistaken. I don't have an ARM machine to test this one, so you will have to dig into `sys/ucontext.h` to check if I got the names right. Ofcourse you should also be checking the faulting instruction in a similar fashion. My best guess as to how it is for ARM is the following (placed along side the other `#if defined(...)` statements:

```
    #elif defined(__arm) // or use what your GCC defines, also check for 32-bit arm mode or whatever...
    uint8_t* code = (uint8_t*)mcontext->arm_pc;
    if (*(uint32_t*)code == /*some instruction*/) {
        mcontext->arm_pc += 4; // skip it!
        return;
    }
```

Comment: @user78663: Thank you, but i want it for `#ifdefined arm` because we work on ARM architectures.

Comment: @user78663: Thank you, i will test it tomorrow (already left from office)and let you know the results. But i am sure it will work in our beagleboard and naviengines. Let me test it and let you know. Till then i upvote your answer and accept it (as i got the know-how). But please check it tomorrow as i will be updating the comments. Huge thanks :)

Comment: @user78663: I made an alternate way to create a SIGSEGV handler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985463/can-we-reset-sigsetjmp-to-return-0-again-reset-sigsetjmp, but facing a problem. If you can please help.

Answer (score 1):

Simply skipping a failing instruction sounds like a recipe for extremely hard-to-track-down errors. However, if you really want to, you can rewrite the IP in the ucontext struct the handler gets as a second or third (I forget which, but don't try any of this without reading the manpages closely anyway) parameter. You'll need to disassemble the faulting instruction for yourself in order to find out how long it is -- which is good because you shouldn't be skipping instructions that you don't understand.

Whatever you do, the result will be *extremely* architecture-specific and nonportable.

Comment: Can we do it using sigsetjmp or siglongjmp?