# Can we reset sigsetjmp to return "0" again (Reset sigsetjmp)?

Tags: c, linux, signals, setjmp

I have written a segmentation fault handler, using sigsetjmp and siglongjmp. Once it goes to the signal handler, i invoke siglongjmp so that the faulty instruction is skipped.

Problem is, i again want to cause SIGSEGV and go to the same handler, but now sigsetjmp will return 1.

How to reset sigsetjmp?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

sigjmp_buf env, env1;

void SIGSEGV_handler(int signal)
{
  printf("Segmentation fault caught\n");
  siglongjmp(env, 1);
}

int main()
{
 void * allocation;
 size_t size;
 static int devZerofd = -1;
 struct sigaction sa, sa1;

 sa.sa_handler=(void*)SIGSEGV_handler;
 sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);

 if ( devZerofd == -1 ) {
     devZerofd = open("/dev/zero", O_RDWR);
     if ( devZerofd < 0 )
         perror("open() on /dev/zero failed");
  }

 allocation = (caddr_t) mmap(0, 5000, PROT_READ|PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE, devZerofd,  0);

 if ( allocation == (caddr_t)-1 )
    fprintf(stderr, "mmap() failed ");

 if ( mprotect((caddr_t)allocation, 5000, PROT_NONE) < 0 )
     fprintf(stderr, "mprotect failed");
 else
     printf("mprotect done: memory allocated at address %u\n",allocation);

 if(sigsetjmp(env, 1)==0) {
      printf("Causing SIGSEGV: 1\n");
      strcpy(allocation,"Hello, how are you");
  }

  /****** This can't be done again as sigsetjmp won't return 0*****/
  /*

  if(sigsetjmp(env, 1)==0) {
      printf("Causing SIGSEGV: 1\n");
      strcpy(allocation,"Hello, how are you");
  }
   */
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have misunderstood how `[sig]setjmp` works.  If you uncomment the code that you think won't work, compile it, and run it, you will see that it does in fact work.

`setjmp` cannot be made to return zero **by calling `longjmp`**.  If you call `setjmp` itself a second time, even with the same `jmp_buf` (as you do here), it will return zero a second time.

You have a bug, by the way: you didn't set up your `sigaction` parameter structure correctly.  You should have done this:

```
struct sigaction sa;

sa.sa_handler = SIGSEGV_handler;
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, 0);
```

The use of `mmap` is a little infelicitous, but not actually *buggy*.  You don't need `/dev/zero` on most current platforms, you can just use `MAP_ANON` (some platforms spell it `MAP_ANONYMOUS`) and a -1 fd argument.  And you should be using `getpagesize` and then asking for a whole number of pages.

Comment: setjmp returns 1 on return from longjmp, right? So you mean if subsequent calls are made, it again returns 0?

Comment: SA_RESTART you mean since it is interruptible function? But it works without that also :)

Comment: More or less, yes.  Remember that each call to `setjmp` potentially returns _twice_: first when control first reaches the `setjmp`, and second if `longjmp` is ever called with the same `jmp_buf` that was used in the `setjmp` call.  The first return always returns zero.  The second return returns whatever the second argument to `longjmp` was, unless that was zero, in which case it returns one instead.  But when you _call setjmp again_, that sets up for a _new_ pair of returns, and the first of those returns zero again.

Comment: mmap -PROT_NONE is perhaps easiest way to create segmentation fault. Because overwrite on strcpy does not always gives SIGSEGV unless you compile it with something like efence.

Comment: Thank you, what you said (about second call to setjmp, again return zero) even the man pages unfortunately does not mention. You helped me clear a lot of concepts.

Comment: The bug is that you didn't initialize the `sa_mask` and `sa_flags` fields, which means you were passing *random numbers* in those fields.  My example shows a safe generic choice for how to initialize them: that's by no means the only valid choice, but I recommend using it unless you have a specific reason not to.  In particular, not using SA_RESTART is *dangerous*, so you should only do that if you *need* a particular signal to interrupt system calls.  Don't leave it out just because it appears to make no difference.

Comment: I understand your point, surely i will initialize it. Thanks again.